# complex numbers with harmonic conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

how do I solve this. please make it as simple as possible I am really bad at maths.

> Let $$u(x, y) = \exp x  \cos y + \exp y  \cos x + xy$$
> Show that u(x, y) is harmonic and find the harmonic conjugate of $u(x, y)$ with $v(0, 0) = 0$.

Comment: You need to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations. They will give you relationships between the partials of $u$ and $v$, which you can integrate to find $v$.

Comment: One would varify that $u$ is harmonic like that, yes. However, to find the harmonic conjugate, we use the Cauchy-Riemann equations. I have demonstrated this method on my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The first Cauchy-Riemann equation is

$$\frac{\partial u}{ \partial x}= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y},$$

which gives us

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = e^x \cos(y) - e^y \sin(x) + y.$$

By integrating, we get

$$v = e^x \sin(y) - e^y \sin(x) + \frac{1}{2}y^2 + \phi(x).$$

Now, we can differentiate this with respect to $x$ and subsitute in the other Cauchy-Riemann equation, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$.

$$e^x \sin(y) - e^y \cos(x) + \phi'(x) = -(-e^x \sin(y) + e^x \cos(x) + x)$$

$$ \phi'(x) = -x \implies \phi(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x^2 $$

Observe that we omit the constant of integration due to the initial condition $v(0,0)=0$.

In conclusion, we have

$$v(x,y) = e^x \sin(y) - e^y \sin(x) + \frac{1}{2}(y^2-x^2).$$